# user input is not showing in logcat android studio

Tags: java, android

`oncheck()` function works properly but `onlogin()` does not works
Also `toString()` is showing red.

When I give some username and password and click login it shows unknown things instead of username and password

I think there is .toString() problem

please tell me how to fix that

```
package com.example.loin;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void onlogin(View view){

    EditText pas=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pas);
    EditText txtt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtt);
    Log.i("Username",txtt.getText().toString());
    Log.i("password",pas.getText().toString());
}
public void oncheck(View view){
    Log.i("info","checked!");
}
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

logcat

```
01-06 21:55:35.060 30039-30039/com.example.loin V/SettingsInterface: invalidate [system]: current 81 != cached 0
01-06 21:55:35.063 30039-30039/com.example.loin D/ActivityThread: holder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@5a3b4ae, holder.provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@455224f
01-06 21:55:35.323 30039-30078/com.example.loin D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 4 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 39, 512, 8
01-06 21:55:37.946 30039-30078/com.example.loin D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8844e00) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
01-06 21:55:37.959 30039-30049/com.example.loin I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1
01-06 21:55:41.220 30039-30039/com.example.loin I/info: checked!
```

Comment: add code of your layout

Comment: Complete layout is too long

Comment: follow a tutorial for andorid. there are a number of them available on the internet. You will be more clear.

Comment: please i have searched a lot in their videos it operates properly

Comment: please tell me why this is error in toString()

Comment: Can you post the xml of th button and edittexts? It is very unlikely that toString call on getText doesn't work.

Comment: Use unique tag for your Log. At this time you have two log tag. Log.e("logproc", ...) . "logproc" is your tag for displaying username and password

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/onlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="488dp"
        android:text="login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.393"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.646" />@dmak2709

Comment: it also does not work @maniaq

Comment: I think your problem is not the layout. where is the point of your click event? some time xml click event does not work. You must have either xml click event or code behind click event . I prefer code behind click event.If you define xml click event please check for existing of the method in your code . However the start poin of your trace is the first line of your event method , otherwise please post more code about the xml click lines or related code behind .2-If you think the issue is inside of your layout please simplify your layout and test again .

Comment: Why you don't have the `android:onClick="onlogin"` attribute in your button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines maybe help you

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/orange_dark"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="log" />
```

and in code behind :

> @BindView(R.id.btn_login) Button _loginButton;

and

> _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("logproc","entering of onclick")
                //your code
        }

    });
```